# Event for blinking line moved in textbox

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have been wondering how to fire an event for when I move the blinking line in a textbox.
I would like this event to contain information for the current (Line, Column) position of the line.
For example if I start out at 0,0 and press enter 3 times how can I get the new coordinates of the line?

Sorry if I didn't explain this question as clearly as possible.

Thanks.

Comment: I think you're talking about the "caret", and that's handled by windows itself so I don't think it's possible without hooking the `WinProc` messages.

Comment: There's no notification for this.  You need to switch to RichTextBox, use its SelectionChanged event.

Answer (score 0):

I assume by blinking line you mean "Cursor" !
Textbox content are considered as plain string, so there is property named as [SelectionStart](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textboxbase.selectionstart.aspx) which you can use to see where your cursor is.

Something like -

```
  int blinkingLinePos = myBigTextBox.SelectionStart;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you move the caret with the keyboard, the events you are looking for are the `KeyUp` and also the `KeyDown` events.

Here is code to calculate the current cursor position:

```
private void textBox1_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    int posInText = textBox1.SelectionStart;
    int lineNr = textBox1.GetLineFromCharIndex( posInText );
    int posInLine = textBox1.SelectionStart - textBox1.GetFirstCharIndexFromLine(lineNr);
}
```

If you change the position by clicking the mouse you can use the same code in the `Click` or `MouseClick` events.